# Pushing aside content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have 3 h1 logos in the HTML with different classes

```
    <h1 class="logo"><span>Rec</span></h1>
    <h1 class="logo2">X</h1>
    <h1 class="logo3">change</h1>
```

When I am hovering above logo2 I want to be able to push logo and logo3 out
the way...currently I am able to push logo3 (to the right) out of the way...however I cannot access the previous logo to push it away (which I would like to push to the left).

```
  .logo2:hover ~ .logo3{
    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
  }
```

How do I access the first logo. I do not want logo2 to move only logo and logo3..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some flexbox tricks do the thing you want. ;).

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

#### Snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo2:hover {
  flex: 1;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="logo logo1"><span>Rec</span></h1>
  <h1 class="logo logo2">X</h1>
  <h1 class="logo logo3">change</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this but the content is side by side I need padding left and padding right. For example x is in the middle and rec is on the left and change is on the right. In a row.

Comment: Could you please explain it a little more, or show picture with desired effect? In your code `h1` elements are one under another, same as in mine.

Comment: So if you switch the display to inline flex and flex direction to row then they will be in order with Rec on the left X in the middle and Change on the right. I want to keep X in the middle and push Rec to the left and Change to the right.  Sorry if it didnt make sense the first time.

Comment: I just edited my answer. You can adjust precise values, but does it do the trick for you, or I still don't understand you?

Comment: This is correct thank you but nothing happens when I hover about mine but I will figure it out thanks.

Comment: One last thing is there a way to do this with inline-flex?

Comment: For container? Sure, but then you also need to define width. `display: inline-flex; width: 100%;`.